# How to make this output faster?

Tags: python, python-idle

```
import time
import sys
try:                                                                        
    shell = sys.stdout.shell
except AttributeError:
    raise RuntimeError("you must run this program in IDLE")

Grid=[[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,]]
counterX=0
counterY=0
while (counterX<=10 and counterY<=19):
    if(Grid[counterY-1][counterX-1]==0):
        if (counterX!=10):
            shell.write("⬛")
        else:
            shell.write("⬛\n")
    if(Grid[counterY-1][counterX-1]==1):
        if (counterX!=10):
            print("⬛", end="")
        else:
            print("⬛")
    if(counterX!=10):
        counterX+=1
    else:
        counterX=0
        counterY+=1
i=0
for i in range (0,44):
    print("")
    i+=1
```

I set myself the challenge of creating a GUI game using ASCII- and in doing so I print out the game grid every single game state (I print it so that it looks like it has replaced the last game state when really it has been printed enough lines down so it looks to be in the same place).I print each tile individually because I need my object to take up a different colour to differentiate background and object. (I haven't yet added the 'if value 1 make the colour red")

Anyway- when printing this out, you can see it print row by row. It's fast- but noticeable. How do I print it all at once?

The new code is to be tested on a fullscreen shell window

Comment: One we can't test your code like that please link your code on here if possible, two we do not see your output that you have mention

Comment: Instead of calling `print` multiple times, first construct the entire string (by appending individual strings to a list and joining the list) and then print it in a single call.

Comment: Push everything to a buffer and then print it, instead of calling `print` a bazillion times.

Comment: 'GUI game using ASCII', printed to a text device is contradictory.  What you should is text-based, not GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The print output will likely appear faster if you run the code directly with python from a command line instead of with IDLE.  It should also appear faster if you print entire lines at once instead of a character at a time.  It might be faster yet if you calculate all lines as one string and print everything at once with one print call.

Comment: 1.  As I've mentioned I'm using colour that which I don't think is possible to achieve on a command-line

2. Like I said I need to make sure an object is visible.

3.<-

Comment: There is no color currently, and print output to the IDLE's shell is not normally colored by usercode.  (IDLE colors normal output as specified on the settings highlight tab.)  If you want colored text, you should use something else that imitates a color terminal, such as VT100.    The existence of sys.stdout.shell is an IDLE implementation detail, and I expect to rename it '_shell' to indicate such before 3.7.3.  There is not much reason to access it directly.